# Why am I leaking memory by Array.join?

Tags: javascript

The memory of this line of code will go up about 100 megabytes, and does not get freed:

```
var json = new Array(100000000).join(",");
```

Why?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6mtx1gyb/ I can't replicate the problem. It may take *some time* (10-30 seconds?) for the memory to be freed, but it *does* get freed eventually, at least in Chrome

Comment: How do you know it doesn't get freed? GC doesn't run until it needs to. Also, given that this is highly artificial code that you wouldn't use in a real project, what are you _actually_ doing where you run into this? You don't predeclare array size in javascript, you just set-as-needed, and any index without explicitly bound content will return `undefined` when dereferenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As reported in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13915837/how-much-memory-does-one-array-element-take), each element of your array will take up nearly a byte.  100,000,000 bytes is roughly 95MB.  The memory reserved for the array will not be released until the garbage collector runs, which is when it deems fit.

As stated in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Release_when_the_memory_is_not_needed_anymore):

> Most memory management issues come at this phase. The hardest task here is to find when "the allocated memory is not needed any longer". It often requires the developer to determine where in the program such piece of memory is not needed anymore and free it.

So the memory will be released when the browser determines it is no longer needed, or when the developer explicitly states that it is no longer needed (demonstrated elsewhere on that page).